# SSH подключение к github на хостинге. Ошибка github.com port 777: Connection timed out

Tags: git, github, ssh

Раньше выгружал изменения с github репозитория на хостинг Макхост путем https (вводил пароль и логин). Теперь необходимо перейти на .ssh. Я создал .ssh ключ по [инструкции](https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/kak-razmestit-sayt-na-hostinge/rabota-s-git-na-hostinge#4), добавил новый ключ в настройках github, заменил ссылку командой `>git remote set-url origin <SSH url>`.

Проверяю подключение `ssh -T git@github.com`, но выводит ошибку `ssh: connect to host github.com port 777: Connection timed out`

При поиске решения, нашел вопрос на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out). Cоздал и добавил в файл `~/.ssh/config` следующее:

```
Host github.com
User git
Hostname ssh.github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-key
Port 443
```

Но это не решило проблемы.

Запустил `ssh -vvv -T git@github.com`. Результат:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 777.
debug1: connect to address 140.82.121.4 port 777: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 777: Connection timed out
```

Запустил `ssh -vvv -T -p 443 git@github.com`. Результат:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/domen.ru/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/domen.ru/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/domen.ru/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/domen.ru/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/domen.ru/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/domen.ru/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/domen.ru/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/domen.ru/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Команда `grep 777 /etc/ssh/*config ~/.ssh/config` Результат:

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config:        Port 777`

Команда `ssh -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/github-key git@github.com` Результат:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi login! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Вроде как соединение установлено, но как выполнять git команды?

Comment: Добавьте к команде `ssh` ключ `-vvv` и посмотрите на каком этапе возникает проблема, возможно проблема в dns к примеру

Comment: `debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.80.186.6] port 777.
debug1: connect to address 140.80.186.6 port 777: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 777: Connection timed out
`

Comment: Лучше сам вывод команд, которые дополнительно проверяете, добавлять в сам вопрос, нажав кнопку "править". А если в команде  ssh добавить ключ `-p 443`

Comment: Попробовал, без результатов. Он пытается найти я так понимаю именно файл id_dsa, но и он есть. Я пробовал и с наименование id_dsa и собственным именем, но все равно не работает. (Оба ключа добавлены в настройках github)

Comment: id_dsa может игнорироваться из-за неверных настроек безопасности. Покажите права на файл `ls -la ~/.ssh/github-key`

Comment: psacln 1675 Aug 17 10:06 /home/httpd/vhosts/domen.ru/subdomains/subdomen/private//.ssh/github-key

Comment: Откуда у вас взялся порт 777? У ssh по умолчанию должен быть 22

Comment: Что у вас написано в `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`?

Comment: Что показывает `ssh -vvv -p 22 git@github.com` ?

Comment: `ssh -vvv -p 22 git@github.com` команда выводит очень много. Последнее строки следующие: `debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
` Если нужно предоставлю весь ответ

Comment: 1. форматированный текст лучше добавлять в вопрос. комментарии для этого не подходят технически. 2. приложите вывод `$ grep 777 /etc/ssh/*config ~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Добавил вывод в вопрос

Comment: `/etc/ssh/ssh_config:        Port 777` — эге. вот где собака и порылась. разбирайтесь, в связи с чем вставлена эта директива. скорее всего, ей (и, вероятно, соседним директивам) там не место. хотя мало ли как у вас локальная сетевая инфраструктура построена: уточняйте у тех, кто её администрирует.

Comment: `ssh -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/github-key git@github.com` так должно работать.

Comment: да, так `ssh -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/github-key git@github.com` работает. Но как теперь git команды выполнять?

Comment: `как теперь git команды выполнять?` — устраните причину ошибки в файле `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.